# Basic Maths question regarding the selection sort formula.

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

I'm training to be a software developer and use Stack Overflow a lot, but I'm afraid some basic Maths has gotten in my way. I apologise in advance for a question that may be too easy to be posted here - if so, just tell me!

We're learning about sorting right now, the first of which is a basic selection sort algorithm. Take the following numbers:

> $9, 5, 17, 11, 12$

It takes the first number and sets it as the minimum number and compares it to everything after it. As 5 is smaller than it, it swaps the two numbers around and moves on.
Next, it takes 5 as the minimum number. If searches the numbers after it and as none are smaller than 5, it stays in position and so on.
It effectively works its way from left to right, leaving it sorted as it goes.

Our lecturer has told us that it is sorted in the following way.

```
To find the smallest, visit n elements + 2 visits for the swap.
To find the next smallest, visit (n-1) elements + 2 visits for the swap.
The last term is 2 elements visited to find the smallest + 2 visits for the swap.
```

This translates into

> $n + 2 + (n-1) + 2 + (n-2) + 2 + \ldots + 2 + 2$

Up until now I'm fine and following it. Then however, he simplifies it to this:

> $\displaystyle \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{5n}{2} - 3$

I have no idea how he has gotten to this. Could anybody explain to me?

Comment: $n+(n-1)+(n-2)+\cdots+2$ is the sum of an arithmetic progression with $n-1$ terms, first term $n$, common difference $1$. The other summands in your sum are all twos, and there are $n-1$ of them.

Comment: I see from looking online that the sum of an arithmetic progression with first term a1 is: Sn = n(a1 + an) / 2
However, I still don't see how I get from that to the simplification (apologies - don't know how to make the formula all neat and tidy like your lettering!)

Comment: The sum of an arithmetic progression with First term $F$, Last term $L$, and Total number of terms $T$, is $T(F+L)/2$. In $n+(n-1)+(n-2)+\cdots+2$, what is the first term? what is the last term? what is the total number of terms? and then what is the sum?

Comment: Thanks for your help (so far!)

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Simple query. I assume that T(F+L)/2 is a rewriting of: Sn = ½ n [ 2a + (n - 1)d ] (which is what I was using).

Comment: No, it's a rewriting of $S_n=n(a_1+a_n)/2$, which is what you wrote (modulo formatting) a few comments up. If I wanted to rewrite $S_n=(1/2)n(2a+(n-1)d)$, I'd say the sum of an arithmetic progression with First term $F$, Common difference $C$, and Total number of terms $T$ is $(1/2)T(2F+(T-1)C)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Gerry I'm sure I'm driving you nuts but I'm still confused. I know Wikipedia is NOT the site to bring up in an academic discussion, but using this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression
I thought that Sn=n(a1+an)/2 was equivalent to Sn = n(a1 + an) / 2

I asked my lecturer who told me that the sequences of 2s had (n-1) elements, which is 2(n-1) = 2n-2. The other sequence can be rewritten as 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + n. However, any sequence of this sort should begin with 1. As it doesn't we must take 1 one off the resulting formula.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: He calculated this formula of the n terms to be n^2/2 + n/2. He then took the 1 off, giving n^2/2 + n/2 - 1.

Putting this with the other formula, he had n^2/2 + n/2 - 1 + 2n - 1, which rearranged gave n^2/2 + 5n/2 - 3. 

Does that make sense to you? Or is that still twisted logic. Again, thanks for sticking by and offering as much help as you have done.

Comment: Never mind Gerry - pretty sure I've got it working. My method of the formula did work, but was a lot longer than yours. The real issue was the fact I was using n terms and not n-1 terms. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "I thought that $S_n=n(a_1+a_n)/2$ was equivalent to $S_n=n(a_1+a_n)/2$." Well, yes --- but where does that get us? "any sequence of this sort should begin with $1$" Whatever would make you write such a thing? Why can't a sequence begin with $2$, or $42$, or $-802$? Anyway, glad you noticed what I wrote in a comment on Jim's answer about your miscounting the number of terms.

Comment: The way I phrased it was pathetic. What I meant was that if the sequence went all the way to 1, it would contain n number of terms. As it didn't, but stopped at 2, it had n-1... or at least that was my understanding of it. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we split off every other $2$ we get two different sums:
$$2 + 2 + \cdots + 2$$
and
$$n + (n - 1) + \cdots + 3 + 2$$

The first is just $2(n - 1)$.  For the second we add:
$$x = n + (n - 1) + \cdots + 3 + 2$$
with
$$x = 2 + 3 + \cdots + (n - 1) + n$$
(add down the columns, so $n + 2, (n - 1) + 3$, etc.) to get
$$2x = (n + 2) + (n + 2) + \cdots + (n + 2) + (n + 2) = (n - 1)(n + 2)$$
so $x = \frac{1}{2}(n - 1)(n + 2)$.  If you add these two totals together:
$$2(n - 1) + \frac{1}{2}(n - 1)(n + 2)$$
you'll get the expression your professor gave you.

Comment: I have to ask - in your second line. Where is the 3 coming from? I thought the last two digits were both 2 (two visits to find the remaining numbers and 2 visits to swap them).
I ask because I've worked it out to n2/2 + 5n/2 - 4 : I'm not sure why I'm one out!

Comment: The last $4$ digits of the sum are $\cdots + 3 + 2 + 2 + 2$, when I take away every other two the last two digits are $\cdots + 3 + 2$.  When you expand that expression the constant term is definitely $-3$.

Comment: Still not fully understanding it, but it's late - I'll keep working away at it tomorrow. Thanks for your help (so far!)

Comment: Can I ask Jim, is this the formula I should be using: ½ n [ 2a + (n - 1)d ] ?

Comment: The reason I ask is that I break down the first line of your answer above to 2(n-1), which becomes 2n - 2. The second part I use the formula for and I do this: n/2(2n + -1(n-1)). I am using n as the first term and -1 as the d (as it is decrementing each time. This simplifies to n/2(2n - n + 1), which becomes n/2(n+1), which becomes n2/2 + n/2.

So I get two sums of n2/2 + n/2 and 2n - 2 : I'm obviously making a mistake somewhere - any idea where? (apologies again for not knowing how to format my text)

Comment: Just to add the 2n-2 isn't over anything. When I multiply it by 2 to put it over 2, I get 4n - 4. Pairing this with my first equation gives me n/2 + 5n/2 - 4 (so off by one)! I've no doubts that I'm wrong, I just don't understand why.

Comment: @AndrewMartin: That formula isn't correct, there should be a constant term.  I'm not sure where you got that one from but I derive the correct one in the post above.

Comment: @Andrew, the number of terms in the sum, $n+(n-1)+\cdots+3+2$ isn't $n$, it's $n-1$.